# Is it possible to have more than one provisioning effect active at the same time?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I just started out my journey in ESO. It seems that only one food/tonic effect can be active at the same time. Does this change later? If yes, how do I increase the number of effects active on me at any one time?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot have more than one provisioning effect active unless it's a perk in the provisioning spot. This does not change later.

Comment: What do you mean by a perk in the provisioning spot?

Comment: Provisioning is how you can make meals. There is a menu there. http://tamrielfoundry.com/crafting/provisioning/

Comment: Thanks :). I've gotten to know more about the game since then.. thanks for the link.

Comment: You're welcome and sorry for the late reply